# Find name in file and then replace their score in python

Tags: python

I have written a game and stored the players scores in a file. However I want to make it so that if a person plays more than once their new scores are stored next to their name, and old scores, in a file. Here is the code I have written so far. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

```
scores = open('scores.txt', 'r+')
scores.write("Name:%s Score:%d---" % (name,score)) 
scorel = scores.read()
print (scorel)
scores.close()
```

P.S as you can probably tell I am new to Python!

Comment: Use `'a+'` as the mode.  One thing, though: you should use `scorel.seek(0)` before reading.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but I suggest you to use a proper database, such as SQLite.

Comment: As @Selcuk pointed out, a database might be best (it scales well) but if you're only dealing with a small dataset, you could also use json that gets parsed to python dictionaries. That would make the lookup/replacement/update very simple as well.

Comment: Are you on windows or unix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a crude way of accomplishing what you needed. Note that this might get slow for very large files. You'll need to create a blank .txt file called `oldscores.txt` manually the first time you run this.

```
def writeScore(name, score):

    name = str(name)
    score = str(score)

    if name in b:
        index = b.index(name)
        f.seek(0,0)
        with open('oldscores.txt', 'a') as f2:
            f2.write(a[index])
        if index == (len(b)-1):
            newscore = a[index].rstrip("\n").split(" ")
            newscore[3] = score
            a[index] = " ".join(newscore)
        else:
            newscore = a[index].rstrip("\n").split(" ")
            newscore[3] = score + "\n"
            a[index] = " ".join(newscore)
        for i in a:
            f.write(i)
    else:
        f.write("\nname: {} score: {}".format(name, score))

with open('scores.txt', 'r+') as f:
    a = f.readlines()
    b = [i.split(" ")[1] for i in a]
    writeScore(PLAYERNAME,SCORE) # Enter the name of the player and the score in here.
```